# Randomize two sets of number in R, not repeating values between groups

Tags: r, dplyr, random-seed

I have this file:

```
ID
1
1
1
3
3
3
7
7
7
```

And I need to assign two sets randomly, (1,2,3) and (5,15,25).

To do this I used this:

```
set.seed(1109201)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set1=sample(c(1,2,3), size=n(), replace=F),set2=sample(c(5,15,25), size=n(), replace=F))
```

and I obtained this:

```
ID  set1 set2
1   1   15
3   1   25
7   1   25
1   2   5
3   2   15
7   2   5
1   3   25
3   3   5
7   3   15
```

but I need different values for `set2` in `set1` and `ID`, like this:

```
  ID  set1 set2
    1   1   15
    3   1   25
    7   1   5
    1   2   5
    3   2   15
    7   2   25
    1   3   25
    3   3   5
    7   3   15
```

`Set2` cannot be repeated into `ID` or `set1`
some suggestion to control these 2 sets?

Comment: Actually, `set2` and `set1` should be randomized considering `ID`, `set2` cannot be repeated into `ID` and `set1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `dplyr` code to the following. Using a 'group_by()` step will have the second sampling occur only within the group.

```
set.seed(1109201)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(set1=sample(c(1,2,3), size=n(), replace=F)) %>%
  group_by(set1) %>%
  mutate(set2=sample(c(5,15,25), size=n(), replace=F)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID  set1  set2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    15
2     1     3     5
3     1     1    25
4     3     3    15
5     3     2     5
6     3     1     5
7     7     2    25
8     7     3    25
```

Comment: Set2 cannot be repeated within set1.

Comment: @CuriousG. I had the wrong grouping variable. Try now.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. Set2 cannot be repeated within ID. My bad, can you help me again?

Comment: @CuriousG. - Just list whatever variables you need in the second `group_by()`. If you need to, you can list multiple variables to group by.

Comment: I tried this, but didn´t work. I have problems to control two variables at same time using this approach. Because each run will be a random assigment.